# Where is the schema of `child-resources` specified?

Tags: onem2m

I'm trying to find where the schema of the result of a `child-resources` query is specified in the xsd. It's clearly not a `primitiveContent` (specified in `responsePrimitive`) because that doesn't contain the named `child-resources` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is in the *CDT-responsePrimitive-v.xsd* file. In *Resourcewrapper* you have "m2m:sg_regularResource":

```
<xs:complexType name="resourceWrapper"> 
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        ...
        <xs:element ref="m2m:sg_regularResource" />
        ...
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="URI" type="xs:anyURI" />        
    </xs:sequence>  
</xs:complexType>
```

In any of the resources that is a "m2m:sg_regularResource" you can find a section like this that allows for "included" child resources:

```
...
<!-- Child Resources -->
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:element name="childResource" type="m2m:childResourceRef" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="m2m:aResourceType" />
        <xs:element ref="m2m:anotherResourceType" />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:choice>
...
```

Comment: is that right? i thought resourceWrapper was just for CREATE? it includes an non-optional URI as well, so it doesn't seem to match.

Comment: Well, it is defined in the resource types, and I don't see another way to add this to the resources.